# $\sup\{\omega,\omega_\omega,\omega_{\omega_\omega},...\}=\text{?}$

Tags: cardinals, ordinals

In [Ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\alpha=\omega_\alpha$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2753842/ordinal-alpha-such-that-alpha-omega-alpha) the question is asked *if* fixed points exist for $\alpha=\omega_\alpha$.

I'm aware that $\varepsilon_0=\sup\{\omega, \omega^\omega, \omega^{\omega^\omega},\ldots\}$.

I'm not sure what the first fixed point of $\alpha=\omega_\alpha$ is called.

$$\sup\{\omega,\omega_\omega,\omega_{\omega_\omega},\ldots\}=\text{?}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it has a standard notation - it's generally just called "the first fixed point of the $\aleph$-function" (for some reason I haven't heard the term "$\omega$-function" nearly as frequently).

Some texts will introduce notation like "$\mathit{lfp}(G)$" for least fixed points of a continuous unbounded ordinal function $G$, at which point this can be written as e.g. "$\mathit{lfp}(\omega_-)$," but I don't think any of these are standard.

Comment: Is it accurate to say fixed points of $\alpha=\aleph_\alpha$ are equivalent to fixed points of $\alpha=\omega_\alpha$? Additionally, is the first fixed point the smallest inaccessible?

Comment: @user784623 Re: your first question, yes, $\alpha\mapsto\aleph_\alpha$ and $\alpha\mapsto\omega_\alpha$ are the same function - remember that $\omega_\alpha=\aleph_\alpha$, the only difference is the context clue to ameliorate the fact that we overload notation w/r/t cardinal and ordinal arithmetic.

Comment: Re: your second question, no, it's vastly smaller. Remember that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves that every continuous unbounded function on ordinals has a fixed point. Thinking about that proof (which is totally constructive!) you'll see that it whips up a least fixed point vastly smaller than the least inaccessible (if it exists).

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, after climbing (more than) an uncountable number of rungs on the ladder, I still haven't actually reached the lowest rung of the large cardinal hierarchy!

Comment: @user784623 Yup. Large cardinals are **large**. Think by analogy of how $\epsilon_0$ looks big at first but is galactically smaller than $\omega_1$. Exactly the same relationship holds here. More precisely, if $\kappa$ is inaccessible, $G$ is continuous and unbounded, and $G(\alpha)<\kappa$ whenever $\alpha<\kappa$, then $G$ has a fixed point $<\kappa$; this is exactly the same argument as behind the fact that $\omega_1$ can't be described as the least fixed point of any continuous unbounded operation on countable ordinals.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response to my intial & follow-up questions. One last question: do you have a reccomendation for a good resource for moving from where I am (fixed points of $\aleph_\alpha$?) to the next step up (inaccessibles?)?

Comment: @user784623 Kunen's book "Introduction to independence proofs" is where I learned this stuff. That said, there's a fair amount of ground between the two :P. Most obviously there are the **worldly cardinals**, those $\kappa$ such that $V_\kappa\models\mathsf{ZFC}$. I don't think Kunen says anything about those.

Comment: Noted. Random aside: Is there any sense in viewing the cardinal numbers as similar to $\mathbb{N}$ & ordinal numbers as similar to $\mathbb{R}$? (eg. in $\mathbb{N}$ there is no number between 1 & 2 similar to how there is no alephs between $\aleph_0$ & $\aleph_1$ - however there are infinitely many ordinals between $\aleph_0$ & $\aleph_1$ similar to how there are infinitely many reals between 1 & 2)

Comment: @user784623 I don't think so. The non-well-orderedness of $\mathbb{R}$ really makes it a bad comparison for anything ordinal-y. In particular, the $\aleph$-function is exactly an order-isomorphism between the class of ordinals and the class of cardinals, whereas it's rather important that $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are not isomorphic.

Comment: @user784623 If you have a discord account I recommend joining the Googology Server, we might be able to help in a way that won't be moved into chat :D

Comment: @L.McDonald Sounds interesting. Do you have a link?

Comment: @user784623 https://discord.gg/HYCeKZ4